# Looking for a book that picks up where Understanding Analysis by Abbott left off?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm currently going through the Understanding Analysis text by Abbott and was interested in what typically comes after once I finish going through this book. Would multivariable analysis of some sort come next? If so, what book would you recommend? Or is there more "single-variable" analysis left to be done?

Edit: I noticed the downvote, would appreciate any advice on how I can improve my answer.

Comment: If you want to be traditional, baby Rudin is a good text.

Comment: The downvote is meaningless. I provide to get to you a upvote.

Comment: There are many options, but a few books that come to mind are Analysis II by Terence Tao,  Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres, and Sheldon Axler's new book Measure, Integration, and Real Analysis.

Answer (score 3):

Since Abbott's book is rigorous, I think you are ready to start more advanced topics like metric spaces.

The classic book to read then is the book "Principles of mathematical analysis" by Walter Rudin (also called Baby Rudin). But I believe this text is not meant to study from, but rather to master the material from.

Therefore, I would first read the book "Mathematical analysis" by Tom Apostol. This treats more or less the same material as Rudin, but in a much more gentle way. If you mastered this book, you can go read Rudin.

Comment: When I first discovered Abbott, I often saw Rudin alongside it which makes me think that alot of topics intersect. Consequently, I decided to go with Abbott as I was willing to sacrifice a bit of rigour for a more intuitive feel for analysis. I am more interested in breadth than in depth so I'd like to head onto the next topic of study rather than dig deeper on a particular topic.

Comment: If you don't want to go deep, don't use Rudin, but Apostol. It will be a much quicker read.

Comment: I am not familiar with Abbott but based on your A, I suggest Introduction To Topology And Modern Analysis, by Simmons.... BTW my edit was to add the 2nd "b" in "Abbott" to conform with the Q.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend looking at Pugh's [**Real Mathematical Analysis**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/144192941X) because, among other features, it's excellent expository merits are similar to those that Abbott's book has. Although a nontrivial amount of the material in Pugh's book will be familiar to you, Pugh's treatment is at a slightly higher mathematical maturity level and the scope of the applications covered (in the text, and *especially in the exercises*) is far beyond that of Abbott and will expose you to many new topics. Also, as you can see from the table of contents, you'll get a good exposure to multivariable topics.

Answer (score 2):

I happen to really like large sections of Koerner's *A Companion to Analysis: A Second First and First Second Course in Analysis*. It starts off with analysis in $\mathbb R$ then moves to $\mathbb R^n$ and eventually metric spaces.  There are even a few bonus problems on complex analysis near the back.  Koerner's book's corrections (and many solutions) are available on his website  https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~twk/ .  The goal of the book in some sense is to give you a new perspective on real analysis after you've already taken a course on it.

That said, you ask whether there is more "'single variable' analysis left to be done" -- an alternative and natural path at this point would be a book on complex analysis... there are many recommendations on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Another good choice is  Ethan  D. Bloch " The real Numbers and Real Analysis" Springer

Comment: Depends. Maybe if the OP is into stuff like constructing the number systems, but most "calculus" things would be covered in Abott I think. But maybe a good book to fill in the gaps in ones understanding.

Comment: I looked over the table of contents:
https://www.amazon.ca/Real-Numbers-Analysis/dp/0387721762
And it seems to cover more or less the same topics as Abbott's book, or are you suggesting that I switch from Abbott over to this book?

Comment: @– ε--δ Sure. My point of view is right in order to go in a deeper way into the foundations of real analysis

Comment: @ Philip In my view this is a great books if you really are interested to understand the foundations of real analysis and in particular the construction of the set of real numbers

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, my only concern is that this book seems (and this is only based off the ToC) to cover the same topics as Abbott and I'd like to cover more ground rather than go in-depth on one particular topic.